# how do I put dialog boxes into a drop down menu using python 2.7 tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, dialog

So I am creating a Blackjack game for a school project. What I would like to do is for the user to play a game of Blackjack as well as having him/her using all of its functionalities. For the past three days I've been trying to figure out how to put in dialog boxes into my drop down menu and I just can't get them to work. I tried everything from my textbook, youtube tutorials, this website and google, but still no help. If anybody could help me out I would really appreciate it! This is my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import * #Imports all definitions from tkinter
import tkMessageBox
import random

class BlackJack:
    def __init__(self):

        #player 1 is you, player 0 is dealer
        self.playerNum = 1

        self.gameIsPlaying = True

        # Create a deck of cards
        self.suits = ['Clubs', 'Spades', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'] # Assigning Suits
        self.ranks = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King'] # Assigning Ranks
        self.values = {'Ace':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '10':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10} #Assignign Values

        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Welcome!", "Lets play Blackjack!") # Displays message "Lets play Blackjack"

        # Creating position of cards
        deckPosition = [400,800]
        playerPosition = [2,700]
        dealerPosition = [2,90]

        self.playerHand = {'Clubs':[], 'Spades':[], 'Hearts':[], 'Diamonds':[]} # Assigning layout of player 1 hand
        self.dealerHand = {'Clubs':[], 'Spades':[], 'Hearts':[], 'Diamonds':[]} # Assigning layout of Dealers hand

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Blackjack 1.0")

        #Create a menu bar
        menubar = Menu(self.window)
        self.window.config(menu = menubar) #Displays the menu bar

        #Create Canvas
        canvas = Canvas(self.window, bg = "dark green", width = 400, height = 500)
        canvas.pack()

        #Creating frames for widgets
        frame1= Frame(self.window)
        frame1.pack()
        frame2 = Frame(self.window)
        Label2 = Label(frame2, text = "Player 1", justify = "left")
        Label2.pack()
        Deal = Button(frame2, text = "New Game", command = self.deal).pack(side = LEFT) # Button to start a new game
        Hit = Button(frame2, text  = "Hit", command = self.hit).pack(side = LEFT) # Button to draw another card
        Stand= Button(frame2, text = "Stand", command = self.stand).pack(side = LEFT) #Button to stop drawing new cards
        frame2.pack()

        # Creates background of GUI
        Photo = PhotoImage(file = "b2fv.gif") # Uses image from "blackjack.gif" file
        label3 = Label(self.window, image = Photo)
        label3.pack()# Holds image in thelabel

        #Create a pull-down menu
        fileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0) # Creates file menu
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label = "Options", command = self.openOptions)
        fileMenu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = self.window.quit)
        helpMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0) # Creates help menu
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "Help", menu = helpMenu)
        helpMenu.add_command(label = "Tutorial", command = self.openTutorial)
        helpMenu.add_command(label = "About", command = self.openAbout)

        self.window.mainloop() #Create an event loop

    # Defines drop down menu
    def openOptions(self):
        return False 

    def openTutorial(self):
        return False 

    def openAbout(self):
        return False 


    def deal(self): 
        self.playerNum = 1
        self.playerHand = {'Clubs':[], 'Spades':[], 'Hearts':[], 'Diamonds':[]} # Deals the cards to player 1
        self.dealerHand = {'Clubs':[], 'Spades':[], 'Hearts':[], 'Diamonds':[]} # Deals the cards to Dealer
        random.seed()

        #assign random cards to dealer and player
        self.playerHand.get(self.suits[random.randrange(len(self.suits))]).append(self.ranks[random.randrange(len(self.ranks))])
        self.playerHand.get(self.suits[random.randrange(len(self.suits))]).append(self.ranks[random.randrange(len(self.ranks))])
        self.dealerHand.get(self.suits[random.randrange(len(self.suits))]).append(self.ranks[random.randrange(len(self.ranks))])
        self.dealerHand.get(self.suits[random.randrange(len(self.suits))]).append(self.ranks[random.randrange(len(self.ranks))])

        print ""
        print ""
        print "Dealer"
        print self.dealerHand   
        print "Player"
        print self.playerHand

    def hit(self):
        # 0 for dealer, 1 for player
        if self.playerNum == 0:
            player = self.dealerHand
            print 'dealer'
        else:
            player = self.playerHand
            print 'player'
        player.get(self.suits[random.randrange(len(self.suits))]).append(self.ranks[random.randrange(len(self.ranks))])
        print player

        self.assessWin(0)

    def stand(self):
        self.playerNum = 0

        while self.countCardValue(0) < 17:
            self.hit()
            print "dealer"
            print self.dealerHand

        self.assessWin(1)

    def countCardValue(self, localPlayerNum):
        numOfAs = 0
        runningSum = 0
        # 0 for dealer, 1 for player
        if localPlayerNum == 0:
            player = self.dealerHand
        else:
            player = self.playerHand

        for suit, ranks in player.items():
            for rank in ranks:
                if rank == 'A':
                    numOfAs += 1
                    runningSum += 11
                else:
                    runningSum += int(self.values.get(rank))

        #factor out 10 if runningSum over 21 and numOfAs != 0
        while runningSum > 21 and numOfAs != 0:
            runningSum -= 10
            numOfAs -= 1

        return runningSum

    def assessWin(self, mode):

        #mode 0, to see if you bust
        #mode 1, after you stand

        if mode == 0:
            sum = self.countCardValue(1) 
            if sum > 21:
                print "You Lose"
            else:
                print sum
        else:
            if self.countCardValue(0) > 21:
                print "You Win"
            elif self.countCardValue(1) > 21 or self.countCardValue(0) > self.countCardValue(1):
                print "You Lose"
            elif self.countCardValue(0) == self.countCardValue(1):
                print "Draw"
            elif self.countCardValue(0) < self.countCardValue(1):
                print "You Win"
```

Comment: You can't put dialogs in menus, if that's what you literally mean. Are you asking how to create menus with items that open up dialog menus, or do you literally mean you want a dropdown menu to contain a dialog box?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  In this case, a minimal example would be a menubar with one dropdown menu with one item.  As Bryan Oakley, you must give the item a commands that open a dialog box.  For instance, in your code, `openAbout` should contain the code that creates a new Toplevel dialog.  Or, you can create the about dialog as part of initialization, but leave it invisible, and have `openAbout` make it visible, and hide it when closed.